# What would be the consequences of the "Stasis bomb"

Tags: magic, time-manipulation

This causes the target to, as long as the caster is concentrating, not experience the flow of time. What would be strategic use cases and consequences of this spell, when combined with various other spells? The spell cannot affect earth, as earth is too large and also magical ground. Spells I was thinking of were telekinesis, necromancy, and various fire and water spells (fireball, volcano-thing, create water, etc.). Apologies if I'm having trouble being clear.

Comment: What various other spells? The folks hoping to answer this need a bit more detail to outline consequences.

Comment: The consequence are that the target does not experience the flow of time. What other consequences do you have in mind?

Comment: I was thinking about what it would do beyond just that. For example, see Mike Serfas' post as to what I was thinking answers would be.

Comment: sounds like Larry Niven stasis fields, which are perfectly reflective spheres

Comment: How do you stop concentrating when you're frozen in time?

Comment: Does "not experience the flow of time" allow to merely remove subjective experience of time passage rather than actually stop the time?

Answer (score 7):

### It's messy.

Magic and physics don't get along well.  They especially don't get on well with test subjects.  Why, one of the first test subjects was an adorable Labrador retriever by the name of Daisy.  Daisy appeared completely undamaged by the field.  Measurements were taken.  An hour later the test was completed, and she was released, and resumed moving the same as she had been before the test.  Which is to say, 700 miles per hour at a 15-degree angle to the subsequent direction of the Earth's rotation, causing her to strike a graduate student at well over 100 miles per hour.  Revisions were made after that - spell to conduct changes in momentum, lighter test subject, fresh Ph.D. project.

The next test was conducted very cautiously using a standard cue ball, and written up by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Billiard_Ball) ... let's just say, making the test subject inertialess so that its velocity can be changed freely is not always the best plan.  It turns out that light, and things moving at the speed of light, are always frozen in time, but that's not precisely novel, though it is certainly useful for military applications.

The next stage of refinement involved a slow transition to near-stasis, permitting the object's speed to be slowly altered without relativistic aberrations.  This, however, was a very rapid change from the object's point of view, and the notes for that day read only that there is more than one way to skin a cat.

It was not long after this that the experimenters had an unfortunate shouting match with some abusive protesters with pitchforks.  Necessity is the mother of invention, and they improvised a plan to impose stasis and momentum changes on a consistent time scale during the period of transformation, i.e. from inside the field of effect.  We're still waiting to see how that turned out.  Hopefully they should be up and publishing any day now?

Comment: Professor's log #276: Creating the spell was a mistake. Undergrads are using it everywhere to prank people who are sleeping by keeping them frozen for a little bit, and then letting them rise slowly until they hit the ceiling.

Answer (score 3):

## Stasis bomb jettisons the target from spacetime

> This causes the target to... not experience the flow of time

Time is one dimension of spacetime. A spell that prevents something from experiencing the flow of time is similar to a spell that prevents something from having e.g. *width*.

The temporal dimension is a little different than the three spatial dimensions. Remove one spatial dimension and you still have something that's logically coherent in the real world: a 2D surface, like a shadow. But if you remove time instead?

The problem there is that while the *target* might be removed from the flow of time, nothing else is. Depending on your purposes, the target's [world line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line) either terminates or becomes irreversibly separated from ours. The rest of time-bound existence hurries onward. Your target is like a man pushed out the airlock of a fast-moving spaceship: they will never again encounter each other, not in a trillion, billion aeons.

---

From our perspective, the target immediately vanishes. Time-traveling observers can go back in time to witness the target in the past, and they can go forward in time to determine that the target does not reappear again in our timeline. The only people who would be able to locate the target after this point would be people who were jettisoned *along with* the target, and any such people would be rendered incapacitated by timelessness and also have no ability to re-locate the cluster of world lines representing normal reality as it hurtles away from them.

From the target's perspective, their immediate surroundings are instantaneously replaced with total black. There is no light, heat, sound, motion. But far more importantly: there is no time, which means the target's lived experience effectively ends the moment their connection with spacetime is severed. While in stasis, the target is neither dead nor alive, and any time-driven processes (e.g. digestion, other spells with time-based limitations) are perfectly halted, usually without any consequence, for the duration. The target has no thoughts, no consciousness, no feelings, no internal experience of any kind.

<strike>If, by some miracle, the target were reunited with the world, they would immediately spring to life, completely unaware of their time in stasis (although they would be just as capable as anyone else of noticing if anything around them changes, seemingly instantaneously).</strike><sup>See note</sup>

The target will remain in this state for eternity, unless somehow restored to spacetime. Targets of the spell do still exist, and they do accumulate, but not in any kind of central "place". Imagine taking a road trip, during which you constantly snack on peanuts that you shell and throw the shells out the window of the moving car. Those shells are like the victims of stasis bomb: yes, the shells discarded by *everyone* are "out there," but they are very dispersed. It will never happen that two peanut shells could "bump into" each other. For our purposes, each shell might as well be on a different planet.

---

The only beings capable of restoring the target to spacetime are those who are capable of existing without time. This is because the core challenge is *locating* a loose world line, which task is literally incomprehensible for any time-bound being. I'm sorry to say that your caster does not have the power to undo the effects of their own "stasis bomb." That is, unless your caster is a super-planar being such as a deity. Stasis bomb is a one-way transition when cast by any mortal caster, regardless of their magical might. Even a mortal who has been given a god's powers would be unable to undo the effects of stasis bomb, because it's not primarily a question of "spell strength," but of finding a needle in an infinite haystack made out of dark matter (not literally). Undo cannot be taught to or learned by any mortal, ever, any more than a human can be taught how to breathe water: if you don't have gills, you drown, period.

This spell almost certainly violates conservation principles, because it removes matter and energy from the physical realm. But hey, that's literally magic for you!

---

Correction: I doubt that a target would experience zero time effects when restored from stasis bomb. This is because of how world lines work.

When the target is stasis bombed, their world-line halts while the rest of the universe moves onward. "Onward" is not a single straight line, but countless helical lines all clustered together and moving in the same direction: helical because everything is ultimately orbiting something else, and all moving in the direction of [time's arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_of_time).

Now it's X years later, and some super-planar godlike creature has decided to "restore the target to life." This is accomplished by locating the tip of the target's world line, dragging it across spacetime to where everything else is, and "grafting"<sup>1</sup> their world line onto something stable here.

That "dragging" portion is what's relevant to us. Wikipedia says that "A world line traces out the path of a single point in spacetime." Everyday orbital motion plus the passage of time will serve to put 4-D distance between the hurtling cluster called "normal existence" and the marooned target.

When the target is restored to the world, the gap must be closed between their "maroon-point" and the normal existence cluster. Some portion of that delta will be a space component, and the rest will be time.

The space component is typically handled automagically by everyday magical teleportation. Any being capable of directly manipulating 4-D world lines is capable of comparatively simpler 3-D teleportation.

The time component is what will get you. Any portion of the time component that is not handled explicitly by some crazy time-travel magic will be applied immediately and retroactively to the target. Your age, how much time you have experienced, is literally just the *length* of your world line. If I suddenly draw a straight line connecting the placetime where we left you to the placetime where we are, I have just made your line that much longer, which effectively fast-forwards your life-clock by that exact amount. It's not the same length as if you'd been moving in a helix like we did: you went straight, and that's the shortest distance between points, so you aged less than everyone else who was present when you got bombed, but you *will* age. This happens when your world line is lengthened, but it doesn't take effect until and unless you are restored to spacetime.

The catch is that the magnitude of the time component doesn't have to reflect the total time that has elapsed for the rest of us. The reason is that the 3-D motion of existence causes us to keep revisiting (roughly) the same spatial positions, even thought our temporal positions never repeat. How much or little of the total delta must be cashed-out in term of time is too complex to explain here, but a quick example may illustrate:

Consider the following without the time dimension. Imagine that you stasis bomb someone on the day of Earth's perihelion, which basically pins them in that exact place. By definition, Earth will return to the same (relative) position exactly 1 year later. Of course, if the sun has moved in that time (it has!), the Earth won't be in *precisely* the same position. But it might be closer to the precise stasis position after 1 year than after just 6 months, because at the ~6-month mark, the Earth is at aphelion instead.

So, if you restore the target at the 1-year mark, they might only age a few weeks. If you restore them at the 6-month mark, they might age *5* months, because the spatial delta captures that much less of the overall delta, leaving the lion's share of the difference to be made-up in the time dimension.

It's for this reason that repeating time cycles play a huge role in the plans and rituals to restore stasis-bombed individuals. If the target has been in stasis for very long, and if they are important, it is quite common to have to plan the restoration years in advance and then carry out the ritual within just a few hours during a narrow window, all to minimize the delta and thus the rapid aging. A crude rule of thumb is that the only way to *not* annihilate the target is to restore them on the exact anniversary of their imprisonment.

As you can see, it is quite a delicate operation to restore a victim of stasis bomb. In most cases, the target dies, crumbles to dust, and disintegrates instantaneously, having aged a substantial fraction of their imprisonment in precisely [5.39×10<sup>−44</sup> seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Planck_time_and_length).

A mortal *might* be able to work out the details to predict how much the target will age when restored, but they would require a lot of detailed astronomical information and an excellent understanding of celestial mechanics, which is not usually available in medieval societies. (This is the stuff that *real* sorcerers learn. There are no private school classrooms filled with wands.)

It's much wiser to get the super-planar being to work out the timing for you. If you time the restoration right, the target may age only 15% of the time they were away. Super-planar beings don't have to do all the math by hand, since they have observed the relevant motions for eternity and have developed "a feel" for it (like how humans are good at throwing objects at moving targets).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The details of the "graft" can only be expressed in the extremely technical and arcane terms of general relativity and planar magic. It *is* magic, so some of it would probably seem like gibberish. Suffice it to say: *your* world line is currently anchored to the same frame of reference as everyone else's, which is why you're experiencing normal life now. Stasis bomb works precisely by un-anchoring the target. Only a sorcerer could even attempt to explain it further. "Grafting" is my gloss for whatever is done to anchor a world line. Presumably, mortals can graft just as easily as planar beings; the difficulty is that mortals cannot search the timeless void for loose world lines in the first place.</sup>

Comment: Explanation of grafting in a 2d spacetime: targets of the spell get moved into a place where nothing exists except for them and other targets from the same spell at the same time, perhaps like a pocket dimension. Grafting is the result of taking the pocket dimension and merging its contents with the main branch. In theory, magitech could be used for worldline repair by helping mere mortals perform grafting and locate the pocket dimension.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of [Serfa's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/82280/mike-serfas):

You completely remove all mass from the target, which is the only way to cause an object to reach true light speed without destroying all creation. Your victim now exists as photons, which do not experience time. You can either let them roam through the universe or trap them in a Bose-Einstein condensate - think of a demi-gas in close to a solute zero temperature - as an interesting set of quantum parameters.

Since there is no known way to reassemble the victim, once the spell ends they disperse in all directions, poetically becoming one with the universe.

Comment: Fair enough. However, stuff doesn't turn into photons when it loses all its mass.

Comment: @4D4850 what happens then? Honest question, I am curious :)

Comment: It does move at the speed of light if it's without mass, but it doesn't turn into photons. Hence, the results would be vastly more destructive, under this interpretation.